# Need to validate a string, whether it contains html or xml using xslt

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

I have an `xsl:variable` whose contents might be HTML or XML or binary.

I'm displaying the value of the variable in a `textarea` in a html page.

If the variable contains HTML or XML data, it is displayed unformatted in the `textarea`.

```
<xsl:variable name="outputString">
//html or xml or binary data goes in here
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<body>
<textarea name="output" cols="20" rows="20">
<xsl:value-of select="$outputString" />
</textarea>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
```

All I need is to display the contents of the variable in a formatted way inside the `textarea` if the contents are either HTML or XML.

Comment: What is your question?  Is it "how to determine whether the text string is HTML, xml or binary?"

Comment: @Naraen, Yes.. I need to determine whether the text string is HTML or XML or binary using XSLT..

Comment: Michael is right.  There is no pure XSLT way to do this.  You will have to use an extension.  The available extension will depend on what language you are using.   Are you doing this from Java, .NET etc?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need processor extensions to do this job, so the answer depends on which XSLT processor you are using.

Comment: +1 Correct answer. In XSLT 1.0, there is no binary or HTML data type. Handling other types than XPath/XSLT data types requires extension functions.

Answer (score 0):

Well I would need to try it out, but I believe you could do the following

```
<xsl:if test="fn:contains($outputString, '<(.*)>.*<\1>')>
</xsl:if>
```

or in your case I would rather use the choose tag.

The [fn:contains()](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_functions.asp) is for XSLT 2.0 and the part I'm not sure is weather it will accept the regex in that format. even more because some places use $1 instead of \1 for referencing the group value.

If you are referencing a XML or HTML that would detect it though.

Comment: hi all,
im using `XSLT 1.0`.. Please help me with any extension functions used with `XSLT 1.0` (`exslt` is preferable) - Dinesh